# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when calling payment service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, payment-processing

I am trying to include Securepay on my website.
In the documentation is written that I can call this url to perform a short test:

```
https://securepay.epayworldwide.com/securepay/register.php?TID=93999966&Userid=123456789012345678901234567890&Password=transactdemotransactdemotransact&Amount=10000&Currency=EUR&Paymode=direct&TransID=AB_1234
```

The link itself works fine but when I try to send the request from a Javascript on my page like so:

```
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
    },
    data: {
        Userid: "123456789012345678901234567890",
        Password: "transactdemotransactdemotransact",
        TID: "93999966",
        Amount: "100",
        Currency: "EUR",
        Paymode: "direct"
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://securepay.epayworldwide.com/securepay/register.php"
});
```

I allways get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://securepay... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mysite...' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Am I doing something wrong here or am I forgeting about something?

Comment: which means the server is not supporting cross domain requests... looks like you might have to use a server side script to send the request to the payment gateway or see whether the gateway supports jsonp

Comment: oh I didn't know that there is a difference between a client side call and a server side call..